# Cakephp FormHelper Create select box

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, form-helpers, cakephp-2.1

i am cakephp beginner.

My Employee Model,

```
         class Employee extends AppModel {
            var $belongsTo = array(
                'Department'=>array(
                'className'=>'Department',
                'foreignKey'=>'department_id',
                'conditions'=>null,
                'fields'=>null
               )
         );
          blah--
```

now in employee add.ctp i want to create a select box which list all the department.
i was going through official cakephp 2.1 documentation ([here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html))
it tells me to add

```
  $this->set('departments', $this->Employee->Department->find('list'));
```

in my controller..

i have no idea to put in which controller ? is it in EmployeesController or DepartmentsController? and in which action of controller?

view to create select box (in add.ctp)

```
         echo $this->Form->input('Department');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you were almost correct - only a minor glitch:

```
echo $this->Form->input('department_id');
```

you need to name the fields as they are in the database.
and if it is a BelongsTo relation than there should be a `department_id` foreign key in your employees table.

PS: cake knows that if you pass down $departments that this array will need to be the options for this form field. so no additional configuration necessary!

```
// in your add action at the very bottom
$departments = $this->Employee->Department->find('list');
$this->set(compact('departments'));
```